# Unexpected Text colour alpha in Jetpack Compose Material Theme

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I discovered today that MaterialTheme applies an alpha to Text's colour. As you can see from the example attached, when I change the background colour, the text's colour appears to be different because it has a transparency value. I can force set a colour (`Text(color = MaterialTheme.colors.onBackground, ....)`) and this works correctly but I don't want to have to do this for every single Text.

Why does MaterialTheme do this? How do I override this behaviour?

Compose and Material Compose Material version: 1.2.1

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun Preview_Playground() {
    MaterialTheme {
        Box(Modifier.background(Color.Green)) {
            Text("Test", fontWeight = FontWeight.ExtraBold, modifier = Modifier.alpha(1f))
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With **M2** (`androidx.compose.material`) the color of the `Text` is defined by the `color` parameter or applying a `TextStyle`.
The default value is [**`Color.Unspecified`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/Color.Companion#Unspecified()).
If color = `Color.Unspecified` and style has no color set, this will be [**`LocalContentColor`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#LocalContentColor()) mixed with `LocalContentAlpha.current`.

In the Text.kt you can find:

```
val textColor = color.takeOrElse {
        style.color.takeOrElse {
            LocalContentColor.current.copy(alpha = LocalContentAlpha.current)
        }
    }
```

With **M3** (`androidx.compose.material3`) it doesn't happen since `LocalContentColor.current` is not mixed:

```
val textColor = color.takeOrElse {
    style.color.takeOrElse {
        LocalContentColor.current
    }
}
```

If you have to use M2, you can define a custom composable for your `Text`, or you can change the `LocalContentAlpha` in the theme for the whole application (not only the `Text`):

```
MaterialTheme(
    colors = colors,
    typography = Typography,
    shapes = Shapes
){

    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalContentAlpha provides 0.5f) {
        content()
    }
}
```

Comment: That does it correctly. Thank you. Mixing colour with the current alpha, and the default alpha value < 1 in M2 are real head scratchers.